# Restrict access to CodeCommit only within workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, workspace, aws-codecommit

We want a CodeCommit repository and the pull request review flow all accessible only within a Linux amazon workspace.

The code, pull requests, etc shouldn’t be accessible outside the workspace. We want to use that approach to secure the code. Does anyone know how we can achieve this?

And if yes, How can it be implemented?

I searched online about this and didn't find anything similar to this case.

Or if you know of any other ways to secure the code? And make sure the code will be copied on the local PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this, by doing this in a different way, either attaching the IAM policy that I created to the user and preventing him to access outside the VPC or by creating an SSH key for each user and configuring the workspace to use this ssh.

Answer (score 0):

whitlist ip of workspace.

eg`{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "codecommit:GitPull", "codecommit:GitPush" ], "Resource": "*", "Condition": { "IpAddress": { "aws:SourceIp": "<ip>" } } } ] }`